# Install McAfee ePO Agent via Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, mcafee

We have recently deployed ePO to our infrastructure, but the Agent will not deploy to all systems. We suspect this is a firewall issue as disabing Windows Firewall generally makes it work.

We have decided to install the Agent via Group Policy to make sure all systems get the it and then ePO will deploy VirusScan on reboot.

Following the manual I have run:

`Framepkg.exe /gengpomsi /SiteInfo=<sharedpath>\SiteList.xml /FrmInstLogLoc=<localtempDir>
\<filename>.log` and then created the GPO, but it never installs.

Has anyone managed to get this working? Or maybe they can suggest a resolution for the failed installs of Agent deploy from ePO?

Comment: How is the GPO suppose to install it?  Startup script, assigned software, something else?  And what does RSOP say on a client that's supposed to be installing this via GPO?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the McAfee KB Article that shows how to deploy McAfee Agent 4.x through GPO. It's pretty straight forward.

[McAfee KB67796](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB67796)

Are you ale to deploy any other software using GPO.  So long as all the files listed in the **McAfee® Agent 4.6.0 Product Guide** are in the same folder as the msi, and that path is readble to the users you should not have any issues.